# Recursive list with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, recursion

I have a csv file with userid and manager fields.
How can I list all userids that report to a specific manager and its direct reports, drilled down to the last user.
Need a quick vbscript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Open the CSV file via ADODB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689123/does-vbscript-have-modules-i-need-to-handle-csv/689224#689224).

You need a `<final_result>` variable (initially empty), and a `<managers>` variable (initially the ID of the one manager you want to create a list for).

Then write a loop that does:

1. `SELECT DirectReports FROM TextFile WHERE Manager IN ('<managers>')`
2. create a list of the `DirectReports` IDs from the resulting `RecordSet`
3. append that list to the `<final_result>` variable
4. assign to the `<managers>` variable a comma delimited string: `"'<id1>','...','<idn>'"`
5. start at #1 unless list is empty

When the loop is through, the final result variable holds all the direct reports.

See - no recursion required. Plain iteration is enough.